# How do I display the open rates of 60 email campaigns?

Tags: email, analysis

My employer wants me to track the opens (and likely clicks at some point) of 50-60 MailChimp/email campaigns on a weekly basis. How best to accomplish this? How would you achieve this goal?

My official title is graphic designer but I'm also a front-end developer and generally pretty tech savvy.

Answer (score 1):

MailChimp has a lot of robust tools for monitoring built in. Step 1 is to make sure that for each of those campaigns that click monitoring and opens are enabled.

> Select the campaign type and choose your list, then you’ll see the
>   Campaign Info and tracking section in the Setup step of the campaign
>   builder. On the left side, you’ll fill in your usual campaign
>   information. The box to the right asks you what you want to track
>   within the campaign you’re creating. We check the opens and HTML
>   clicks boxes for you by default, but if you want to track plain-text
>   clicks or add Google Analytics tracking (more on that later), you’ll
>   need to check the appropriate box. Clicks are automatically tracked
>   for users on free plans.

[image]

Once you have that enabled or verify that it has been, you can check the generated reports to see the statistics.

> To view your MailChimp campaign reports, just log in to MailChimp and
>   click the Reports tab. You’ll see a list of campaigns you’ve sent.
>   Click on the name of a campaign to see its report.

[image]

> You’ll go to a screen that looks something like this—it’s your Report
>   Overview.

[image]

These are the basic stats you’ll find in MailChimp campaign reports—you
should know exactly what they mean, and how you can use them to manage
your list and target your audience.

> 1. Recipients: This one’s fairly self-explanatory.
> 2. Opens: This is the amount of your readers who opened your email.
> 3. Unopened: The inverse of #2.
> 4. Clicks: How many readers clicked on links in your email.
> 5. Unsubscribers: This one’s kind of a bummer—the number of people who chose to stop receiving your campaigns. We see an average unsubscribe
>      rate of less than half of one perfecent. Much more than that, and you
>      might be doing something wrong.
> 6. Complaints: When you get junk mail, you can click a button that says “Junk” or “Report as Spam.” Every time you do that, a report and
>      copy of the offending email goes to your ISP. Your ISP sends a warning
>      to the sender that says, “too many complaints, and we’ll block future
>      emails from you.” When you send with MailChimp, we track the
>      complaints your recipients submit. We also automatically remove people
>      who complain about you from your list.
> 7. Successful Deliveries: Some emails bounce or get blocked by spam filters and firewalls. This number shows you how many of your emails
>      actually got through to your recipients’ receiving servers.
> 8. Bounced: The inverse of #7.
> 9. Total Times Opened: This includes multiple opens per user, so don’t let the stat go to your head. It’s not a totally useless stat,
>      however. For example, if you sell banner advertisements in your email
>      campaigns, then an open is an impression, and you’ll want to show your
>      advertisers total impressions.
> 10. Last Open: Some people post special landing pages that they point their campaigns to. Over time, they have tons of landing pages on
>       their server, and they want to delete some to make room. But what if
>       some of your recipients are still opening that email you sent five
>       months ago? This stat will help.
> 11. Clicks/Unique Open: The percentage of licks that came from unique opens. Which is to say: We don’t include people who opened the email
>       more than once.
> 12. People Who Clicked: Another self-explanatory one, but it’s perhaps worth noting that if you have five readers click on your email 20
>       times, this stat will say five, not 100.
> 13. Total Clicks: This is the total number (the 100 from #12). It’s also a handy way to determine how much overall web traffic you’ll get
>       to your website (or other websites you link to) after a campaign is
>       sent.
> 14. Last Click: See #10, except it’s clicks instead of opens.

TADA!
You now are an expert at tracking your campaigns!

To further dive into advanced tracking and analytics but you can read up on that on your own. MailChimp is SUPER EASY, user-friendly and has a lot of online resources to learn from.

[Here's the pdf I pulled the information from.](http://static.mailchimp.com/www/guides/understanding-reports/package/understanding-reports.pdf) It was a quick Google search away.